# laravel Add a link to array correctly without error

Tags: php, laravel, api, laravel-8, laravel-9

laravel add url string to array

```
 if($request->has('images')){
       $data = explode(",",$request->images);
        foreach($data as $image){
             $imageName = 'test'.'-image-'.time().rand(1,1000).'.'.'png';
             Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
             $imagesName[] = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/".$imageName;
         }
        }
```

The problem is that the link is saved in the databases like this

```
["http:\/\/127.0.0.1:8000\/storage\/test-image-1666197127684.png"]
```

i need to save it like this

> ["http://127.0.0.1:8000/storage/test-image-1666197127684.png"]

Comment: Are you sure it's being saved that way? And how are you saving the images in the database? That looks like a normal json encoded string that escapes certain characters.

Comment: You haven't shown us a) the code which saves the link to the database, or b) the code which generates the strings you've shown, I mean `["http:\/\/..."]`.  Edit your question show us the relevant code for saving that value, and retrieving/displaying that value.

Answer (score 0):

Try this it will save dynamically the server URL path:

```
if($request->has('images')){
               $data = explode(",",$request->images);
                foreach($data as $image){
                     $imageName = 'test'.'-image-'.time().rand(1,1000).'.'.'png';
                     Storage::disk('public')->put($imageName, base64_decode($image));
                     $imagesName[] = request()->getSchemeAndHttpHost()."/storage/$imageName";
                 }
                }
```